# How to get Amazon Product price using VBA selenium and save in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a VBA script that scrapes product title and price into an excel sheet. I am using SeleniumWrapper library to get the links from Column A and scrape the Amazon product urls row by row. Row1 contains Amazon url(A1), product title(B1), and price(C1). I'm new to VBA. My goal is to get this records into excel and create a schedule that automatically runs the script daily. My challenge is getting the price from amazon. Currently, the html for the Amazon price is in this order;

```
<span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">$</span><span class="a-price-whole">29<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">99</span></span>
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub AmazonApple_Select():



Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Dim bot As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Dim FF As Object
Dim intRowPosition As Integer
Dim keys As New SeleniumWrapper.keys
Dim amazonPrice As WebElements, amazonText As List

selenium.AddArgument "start-maximized"
selenium.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com"
selenium.setTimeout ("120000")
selenium.setImplicitWait (5000)
intRowPosition = 3

selenium.Open Sheet1.Range("A" & intRowPosition)

intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1

While Sheet1.Range("A" & intRowPosition) <> vbNullString

    selenium.SendKeys keys.Control & "t"
    selenium.Open Sheet1.Range("A" & intRowPosition)
    
    On Error Resume Next:
        'Sheet1.Range("B" & intRowPosition).Value = selenium.FindElementById("productTitle").Text
        Sheet1.Range("B" & intRowPosition).Value = selenium.getTitle 'Amazon and Apple title
        Sheet1.Range("C" & intRowPosition).Value = selenium.findElementByCssSelector(".rf-bfe-header .as-price-currentprice span").Text 'Apple
               
        Sheet1.Range("C" & intRowPosition).Value = selenium.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div']/div[1]//span[2]/span[2]").Text 'Amazon whole price
        Sheet1.Range("D" & intRowPosition).Value = selenium.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div']/div[1]/span/span[2]/span[3]").Text 'Amazon fraction price
        Sheet1.Range("C" & intRowPosition).Value = selenium.FindElementByXPath("(//div[@class='rc-prices-currentprice typography-label'])[2]/span").Text 'iPad Pro price

    intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1

Wend
selenium.Close

End Sub
```

This script can fetch data from Apple store into the excel sheet without any errors. But I can't get the Amazon price right. Column A contains the Amazon and Apple URLs. I want to be able to fetch Amazon price data into Colum C only with minimal code using Selenium VBA.I want to schedule this script to run daily. Please if you think doing this will be better in python selenium, kindly provide code or guide here.

Here is an example url for Amazon in Column A: `https://www.amazon.com/dp/B097PPJRXS`
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar w/ VBA's SeleniumWrapper, but I was able to get it in Python's version of Selenium (it probably works very similar based on your code).  I was able to get the price using the CSS selector.  Try the following:

```
selenium.findElementByCssSelector(".a-price-whole").Text
```

Comment: The class you have provided (`.a-price-whole`) does not get the actual price of the product. It returns 16 different elements on the product page. I need the Whole number, the decimal and the Fraction of the Amazon price. All these data should be in saved in one cell in the Excel sheet.

Comment: You can inspect each element, but if there are multiple elements try:

`selenium.findElementByCssSelector(".a-price-whole")[0].Text`

Comment: It doesn't return the whole price and the fraction still. So I used python selenium to double check `price = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.a-price-whole')))
print(price.text)` This returns only the whole price which is `13` and doesn't return the decimal and the fraction which is `.99`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me using Windows, Excel, VBA and Selenium.
There appears to be a bug in the `.Text` method as it returns nothing for the `a-price-decimal`.
Excel will display a decimal point if one is returned.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbAmazonPrice()
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim we As WebElement
    sURL = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B097PPJRXS"
    Call driver.Start("edge", sURL)
    driver.Get (sURL)
    driver.Window.Maximize
    Set we = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body")
    Sheet1.Range("A1") = "a-price-whole"
    Sheet1.Range("B1") = we.FindElementByClass("a-price-whole").Text
    Sheet1.Range("A2") = "a-price-decimal"
    Sheet1.Range("B2") = we.FindElementByClass("a-price-decimal").Text
    Sheet1.Range("A3") = "a-price-fraction"
    Sheet1.Range("B3") = we.FindElementByClass("a-price-fraction").Text
    Sheet1.Range("A4") = "a-price-symbol"
    Sheet1.Range("B4") = we.FindElementByClass("a-price-symbol").Text
    MsgBox we.FindElementByClass("a-price-decimal").Attribute("outerHTML")
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```